# When should I use a conda environment?

Tags: python, anaconda, conda, miniconda

I work on a Linux machine and have recently started working more with data science so I figured that I would give conda a try. I see the benefits of working in different environments when using different packages, but I fail to understand the scope of conda environments. Should I be in a conda environment all the time? What effect does it have on, lets say, updating my system? Or writing C code?